# Java pass "null" to overloaded methods

Tags: java

Can someone explain me why if a run this code

```
public class MainClass{

   public void method(Object obj){
       System.out.println("+++++++++obj");
   }

   public void method(A a){
       System.out.println("**********a");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       new MainClass().method(null);
   }
}
```

I get this result:

```
**********a
```

How can a **null** reference be resolved to an "A" object reference?

Comment: `null` can be resolved to anything and thus the most specific method will be used. Add a method with parameter type `B` and the compiler should complain about ambiguous parameters.

Comment: This isn't overriding, it's overloading - and it doesn't seem *terribly* obscure to me. Would you expect `A a = null;` to fail to compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most specific method  chooses at run. `A` is more specific than `Object` and

```
A a = null;
```

is valid.

Hence when you pass `null`, its choosing `(A a)`.

Here is the [`Language specification`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)